# Using Python code to write into a python 3 shell to develop a database

Tags: python, database, shell

I am struggling to get my python code to write to the command line and access a python 3 shell. I have the code:

```
arr = ['python', 'from taskingDaemon import db', 'db.create_all()', 'exit()']
for command in stream:
     os.system(command)
```

This calls the python line, but then stops when the command line enters a python 3 shell.  I have tried to create the databases utilizing sqlite3 tools but was unsuccessful.  If anyone could advise how to get python code to continue executing the lines even after the `>>>` appears, indicating the python shell has been executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the first round of the loop you did `os.system('python')` which executes the python shell. Python lets you run a command from the command line, so you can

```
os.system('python -c "from taskingDaemon import db;db.create_all()"')
```